# Files cannot be found when relative to property file in Java/Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

My Java project uses Gradle. I'd like to include a configuration folder `conf` when distributing the application with the task `distZip`.

This is an excerpt from my current project structure.

```
src    
|-- dist
    |-- conf
        |-- application.properties
        |-- keystore.jks
        |-- truststore.jks
```

The `conf` folder is successfully distributed.

In my `main()` I load the properties with `new File("src/dist/conf/application.properties")` which works fine.

The `application.properties` contains two properties:

```
keystore.location = ./keystore.jks
truststore.location = ./truststore.jks
```

When starting the application from IntelliJ it works finde but when starting the distribution it cannot find the `keystore.jks` and `truststore.jks` because `src/dist/conf` does not exist but only `conf`.

How can I make sure that these files are found?

Comment: Doesn't Gradle or Java find these files?

Comment: Java itself cannot find them.

Comment: Did you try to use a absolute path? Just for testing

Answer (score 1):

Your *src/dist/conf* folder is no resource folder for the java gradle plugin (and IntelliJ). It is just picked up by the application plugin (`distZip` task). IntelliJ sets the execution directory to the root path of the project. So it is just a coincidence that the *src/dist/conf/application.properties* can be read.

Move the files in from *conf/dist* folder to *src/main/resources* and they will be found by the `processResources` task and this folder should also be recognized by IntelliJ as a resource folder. Your classpath will have the *resource* node as root, so that you can use an absolute classpath to get to your files. (straight-forward sample: `new File(YourClass.class.getResource("/dist/application.properties").getFile())`)

I think that it will take much more effort to read the files in the *conf/dist* folders, because they are not part of the classpath.